# Identifying accuracy and dropped features with AutoML (ml.net)

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net, automl

I have been playing with ML.Net AutoML and having a blast with it. I still have some questions and hope someone either could help or guide me in the right direction with some of my questions.

**Question 1:**
I have a trained binary classification model from AutoML. This resulted in a top 5 list of algorithms based on highest accuracy, and I ended up with a SdcaLogisticRegressionBinary binary classification model with an accuracy of 89%.

Now when I do my evaluation the accuracy drops to 84%. Would this mean the original training model was overfitted by 5%? Would it be fair to say that the accuracy of my model is not 89% but actually 84% based on the evaluation?

**Question 2:**
AutoML also drops features during training where needed. Is there a way to retrieve the actual list of features that was included in the final model, e.g. determine which features were dropped and didn't improve the accuracy of the model?

When I inspect the final model, the OutputSchema tends to always include all the features based on the initial training data.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this mean the original training model was overfitted by 5%?

This terminology says nothing, and it is never used. Sadly, "overfitting" is a much abused term nowadays, used to mean almost everything linked to suboptimal performance; nevertheless, and practically speaking, overfitting means something very *specific*: its telltale signature is when your validation loss starts increasing, while your training loss continues decreasing, i.e.:

[image]

The 5% "margin" between your training and validation accuracy is another story altogether (it is called [generalization gap](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/07/predicting-generalization-gap-in-deep.html)), and does **not** signify overfitting.

> Would it be fair to say that the accuracy of my model is not 89% but actually 84% based on the evaluation?

As you have already probably suspected, "accuracy" by itself is an ambiguous term; truth is that, in practice, when used without any other signifier, it it usually taken to mean the *validation* accuracy (practically nobody bothers for the exact value of the training accuracy). In any case, the correct report of your results would be - training accuracy 89%, validation accuracy 85%.

Comment: Crystal clear. So in my case the 89% is simply the accuracy of a model based on the training dataset. And 84% based on the test dataset, e.g. examples it hasn't seen before.

Comment: @MichaSchopman and since it was crystal clear, would you mind kindly accepting the answer? Thanks